# ssh to Ubuntu Server hangs after 30 seconds of inactivity

Tags: server, ssh

Lets say I ssh to my 13.04 server from my Linux box and then `vim file` and do some text editing.  If I pause for 30-60 seconds, considering what to type, then the terminal will hang.  The cursor box continues to blink, but nothing in the terminal changes.  It takes no keyboard input.  It never disconnects, never gives me another message, display any errors.  I have to close the console window to get out of it.

What is this, how can I get out of it when it happens, and how can I prevent it from happening in the future?

The result of `grep -Hi Alive /etc/ssh/ssh*_config` on the server:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config:ServerAliveInterval 30 
/etc/ssh/sshd_config:TCPKeepAlive yes
```

There are no results for `grep -i alive /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: Could you post the result of `grep -Hi Alive /etc/ssh/ssh*_config` on the server?

Comment: Hmm, and `grep -i alive /etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client (sorry, that one should have been in the client in the first place) ?

Comment: There is no result for ` grep -i alive /etc/ssh/ssh_config `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the issue is that you've not set `ServerAliveInterval` on the client. As explained in `man ssh_config`:

> ServerAliveInterval
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
>        been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through
>        the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The
>        default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
>        the server, or 300 if the BatchMode option is set.  This option
>        applies to protocol version 2 only.  ProtocolKeepAlives and
>        SetupTimeOut are Debian-specific compatibility aliases for this
>        option.

So, if I'm right, simply adding this line to your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file *on the client* should fix the issue:

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

That will send the keep alive messages every 30 seconds. That's kind of frequent but once you make sure that fixes it, you can reduce the frequency as needed.

Comment: This solution fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks of saving me some precious moments. Sending hugs over the internets.